# Tentando colocar as imagens uma ao lado da outra com o display; flex

Tags: css, grid, flexbox

```
<section class="flex">
    <div><img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco</div>

    <div><img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco</div>

    <div><img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco</div>

    <div><img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco</div>

    <div><img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco</div>

    <div><img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco</div>
</section>
```

css abaixo:

```
img{
    max-width: 10%;
    display: block;
}

\*css flexbox*\

.flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 880px
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex > div {
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    margin: 10px;
```

Estou tentando alinhar as imagens lado a lado, ficando 3 imagens em cima e 3 embaixo como se fosse uma pagina de uma loja, exibindo produtos

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente o erro o erro foi falta de atenção na hora de escrever o código o comentário não foi feito da maneira correta

Errado `*css flexbox*\`

Correto `/* css flexbox */`

E a falta de um ; depois do `max-width: 880px` evitou que o próximo estilo `margin: 0 auto;` carregasse

Ajustando isso seu código estará quase pronto, falta somente ajustar os cálculos o seu box que está agrupando os produtos tem **880px** de largura e cada produto tem margin de **10px** como vc quer 3 produtos por linha e esse margin é em todos os lado, devemos subtrair 60px de 880px e ai sim dividir por 3

Dessa forma 880-60=820/3=273px

Então ao invés de `flex: 1 1 200px;` o correto seria `flex: 1 1 273px;`

```
img{ max-width: 10%; display: block; }

/*css flexbox*/

.flex{ display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; max-width: 880px; margin: 0 auto; }

.flex > div { flex: 1 1 200px; margin: 10px; }
```

Lembrando que é uma boa prática "dar nomes" a suas div's através das classes

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de fazer isso é você separando as imagens de 3 em 3 dentro de divs, como o demonstrado abaixo:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column
}

.row1, .row2 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px 5px 
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
            <div class='row1'>
                <img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco
        
                <img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco
        
                <img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco
            </div>
            <div class='row2'>
                <img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco
        
                <img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco
        
                <img src="fotocurriculum/moletom.jpg" alt="moletom"> Moletom Branco
            </div>
        </section>
```

Como no exemplo é só você centralizar tudo com o `justify-content` e `align-items` e setar o `flex-direction` para coluna que fica do jeito esperado!